# ReactStrap input group bug (not 100% width)

Tags: css, reactjs

Does anyone have this bug where an input group addon or dropdown is taking up half of the entire width instead of a 100%. (basically the InputGroupButton is taking up the other 50% so 100% width spread automatically between two elements but in the Reactstrp docs there's every indication that this is goes against expected behavior)

I want my input group to be 100% width like the rest.
https://reactstrap.github.io/components/input-group/

this is what I currently have :

[image: what I currently have]

and if I open Inspect Element :

[image: no extra margin or padding consumed by the inputGroupButton]

[image: same]

you can see that the InputGroupButton isn't setting a padding or a margin like "auto" or something similar which you'd expect to be responsible for this.

here's the small snipet of react render concerning the password field :

```
render() {
    return (
        <Label className="password">
            <InputGroup>
                <Input
                    className="password__input"
                    placeholder="Mot de Passe"
                    type={this.state.type}
                    onChange={this.passwordStrength}
                />
                <InputGroupButton><Button onClick={this.showHide}>
                    {this.state.type === 'password' ?
                        <i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" />
                        :
                        <i className="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true" />
                    }</Button></InputGroupButton>
            </InputGroup>
            <span
                className="password__strength"
                data-score={this.state.score}
            />
        </Label>
    );
}
```

and here's the render that calls it (it's called at "ShowPassword") :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button color="info" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Créer un compte</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    Veuillez renseigner les champs ci-dessous afin de créer votre compte
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input placeholder="E-mail" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <ShowPassword />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input placeholder="Confirmer"/>
                    </InputGroup>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Envoyer</Button>{' '}
                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Annuler</Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please guys I can't find anything on the web on this issue.

Comment: there's a bounty now please help!

Comment: if you can reflect this issue on jsFiddle that would be very helpful to answer

Comment: I don't know how to use reacstrap in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. You are using reactstrap an unintended manner. reactstrap is based on [Bootstrap CSS Library](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/). Bootstrap expects you to structure your elements and CSS classes in a certain way it describes in the documentation. If we don't follow them, we can't get the expected result.

As an example, Bootstrap only expects certain elements like `Input`, `InputGroupButton` and `InputGroupAddon` inside the `InputGroup`. But in your case, if we replace `ShowPassword` with its actual JSX structure, you will have a `Label` inside `InputGroup` and another `InputGroup` inside the `Label`. What is why it is not rendered as expected.

First, to wrap your `ShowPassword`, you should use a `div` instead of a `Label`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="password">
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          className="password__input"
          placeholder="Mot de Passe"
          type={this.state.type}
          onChange={this.passwordStrength}
        />
        <InputGroupButton>
          <Button onClick={this.showHide}>
            {this.state.type === "password"
              ? <i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" />
              : <i className="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true" />}
          </Button>
        </InputGroupButton>
      </InputGroup>
      <span className="password__strength" data-score={this.state.score} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then you should remove additional `InputGroup` which wrap your `ShowPassword` component.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="info" onClick={this.toggle}>
        {this.props.buttonLabel}
      </Button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.state.modal}
        toggle={this.toggle}
        className={this.props.className}
      >
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Créer un compte</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          Veuillez renseigner les champs ci-dessous afin de créer votre compte
          <InputGroup>
            <Input placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" />
          </InputGroup>
          <InputGroup>
            <Input placeholder="E-mail" />
          </InputGroup>
          <ShowPassword />
          <InputGroup>
            <Input placeholder="Confirmer" />
          </InputGroup>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
            Envoyer
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
            Annuler
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hopefully, now you will get the expected the result.

Comment: well that makes me feel dumb :P why didn't it jump out at me that I'm wrapping the thing twice?? thanks man